# C++11 compare and swap acquire/release semantics

Tags: c++, c++11, atomic

Let's assume I have the following code (toy examples):

```
std::atomic<K *> data;
K *old_value = NULL;
K *new_value = new K();
if (!data.compare_exchange_strong(old_value, new_value, m1, m2)) {
    delete new_value;
}
do_something(old_value);
```

Or

```
std::atomic<K *> data;
K *i = data.load(m3);
K *j;
do {
   j = i + 1;
} while (data.compare_exchange_weak(i, j, m4, m5);
do_something(j);
```

What are valid values of `m1`, `m2`, `m3`, `m4` and `m5`?
My reading is that all can be `std::memory_order_relaxed` as the whole code strongly depends on the result of previous operations (assuming `do_something` just uses the pointer and don't alter the global, shared state). Is my reading correct?

Comment: Before anyone say it - I know that in 99% cases I can just write `std::memory_order_seq_cst` and don't see any impact on performance of code but I just what to understand memory ordering in C++11.

Comment: Are you sure you run on a platform where there is a difference?

Comment: @BoPersson: That what I meant by 99% of cases - I'm more interested if my understanding is correct then practical aspects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This question only makes sense in a multithreaded scenario with a well-defined shared state. Without knowing what the other thread does, I can only assume that it reads/writes `data`. With just this single point of synchronization, all-relaxed ordering should do just fine. For any given atomic considered independently of other sync points, operations will still be atomic, and their relative ordering will still be correct.

Now, if the shared state consisted of several variables (that's where the "ordering" comes into play), it would be a totally different story; and you would have to worry about acquire/release/etc. semantics. In this case:

`relaxed`

- does not guarantee that changes to several variables from one thread will be visible to another thread in the same order;
- does not guarantee that changes to several variables made independently from different threads (e.g., thread 1 sets `data1`, and thread 2 sets `data2`) will be visible to all the other threads in the same order.

`acquire/release` (when used on every read/write, respectively; for different patterns of ordering arguments the first item may become more relaxed)

- guarantees that changes to several variables from one thread will be visible to another thread in the same order;
- does not guarantee that changes to several variables made independently from different threads will be visible to all the other threads in the same order.

`seq_cst` (again, when used on every read/write):

- guarantees that changes to several variables from one thread will be visible to another thread in the same order;
- guarantees that changes to several variables made independently from different threads will be visible to all the other threads in the same order, whatever it may be.